# Expanding a UITableViewCell with CoreAnimation

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-animation

I'm trying to expand a UITableViewCell to fill the entire screen using CoreAnimation.

How can I animate a TableViewCell so that it looks like the cell is expanding to fill the entire screen?

I will then push another ViewController in the completion block of the animation (without the user noticing).

Comment: Is there any special reason you are trying to accomplish that? Usually when you touch a tableviewcell it just drills down to the next controller.

Comment: It's the same graphic, just bigger, so I would like to zoom out rather than pushing in a bigger version of the same graphic form the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to take the actual cell and expand it to fill the screen, because the TableView is managing the cell and could respond rather poorly to the cell's size going crazy all of a sudden.

What I would do is make a 'copy' of the cell using your own class extending UIView, display the copy directly above the cell of the table view (let me know if you need details on that step or if you can figure it out yourself), and then animate *that* to fill the screen.

For tips using CoreAnimation and layers, go try google - there's a lot out there already on the subject.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had in mind too. It's not very clean, but you're probably right that expending the actual cell could result in a mess.